# executemany throws error when I try inserting a list of tuples generated by list comprehension; same list works if it's hard-coded

Tags: python, sqlite, executemany

executemany throws error when I try to insert a list of tuples that is generated using list compression, but works when insert the same list if it’s hard-code. When I try:

```
a=[(i[0][0],i[0][1],i[0][2],i[1][0],i[1][1],i[0][5]) for i in zipList_updates]
c.executemany('INSERT INTO Households VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)',a)
```

I get: InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 4 - probably unsupported type.

But when I hard-code the list of values as:

```
b=[('1000000US371830501001017', 'White', 2, '150-200K', 184, 'Renter'),\
('1000000US371830501001017', 'Asian', 2, '125-150K', 250, 'Renter')]
```

and try:

```
c.executemany('INSERT INTO Households VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)',b)
```

it works fine. When I check a==b , I get True.

I don't understand how it's possible as a and b seems to be the same thing.

Comment: Did you check that `a` and `b` are indeed the same? Try printing the value of `a`.

Comment: Yes, I did. I printed the values they are identical, and as I said a==b returns True.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect wrapping items in `str()` may help:

```
# factor out a bit of copy-paste
def makeTuple(record):
  indexes = ((0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 5))
  # note the str↴
  return tuple(str(record[j][k]) for (j, k) in indexes)

a = [makeTuple(i) for i in zipList_updates]
```

Try checking the *type* of items in tuples of `a`. Definitely in tuples inside `b` items are strings. I have no idea what can be in `zipLiat_updates`.

I have seen that objects feign the behavior of strings by clever proxying of attributes, including equality. But the illusion is dispelled if such an object is passed to a C library like `sqlite` or other database drivers: a type error happens, because they expect a real string.

Comment: Casting to string worked. But it seems that the problem is somehow related to integer values, not the string values. I only changed the 3rd and 5th items to string. Although my 3rd and 5th field types are integer, the following works:  a=[(i[0][0],i[0][1],str(i[0][2]),i[1][0],str(i[1][1]),i[0][5]) for i in zipList_updates] . Those integers don't cause any problem for b though. The other solution that worked too, was to cast the entire list to an string then using some messy string methods recreated the list and nested tuples from the string.

Comment: Pretty funny. BTW, you can probably replace the messy string methods with `import json; a_json = json.dumps(a); recreated_a = json.loads(a_json)`. I'd rather avoid both, though, and make sure I understand what's going on with the integer parameters. For instance, the parameters you receive can be [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html), they print, compare and otherwise behave as normal numbers (only more precise), but a C library won't take them where it expects an integer.